# Image not displaying in view. Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my Laravel project I'm trying to load an image into my view using blade but it displays as a broken link. I inspect it with firebug and the src is pointing to the image but nothing is displaying.

My image is located in my project's public/images/users/3/profilePictures/

Here is my `<img>` in the view.blade.php

```
<img class="com-profile-picture" src="images/users/{{ $follower->id }}/profilePictures/50thumb-{{ $follower->profilePicture->url }}" alt="{{ $follower->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ $follower->last_name }} Profile" width="50" height="50">
```

However I get this when I load the page:

[image]

When I inspect the image with firebug I see this:

[image]

That is the correct src and the image does exist in my public/images/users/3/profilePictures/ directory

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `src` of `firebug html` & `code` different, `html` says, `../users/3..`, but u say correct `src` is `../users/2..`

Comment: ah, miss type on my question, I'm still experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may be caused you are in a route which does not represent the base URL. You should generate the URL for your assets relative to the `public/` folder. Use `URL::asset('path/to/asset')` to generate the URL.

```
{{ URL::asset("images/users/{$follower->id}/profilePictures/50thumb-{$follower->profilePicture->url}") }}
```

Or as @lukasgeiter mentioned you can simply use `asset('path/to/asset')` helper.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohebifar and lukasgeiter

Comment: This is just save my life :D

Answer (score 18):

You can try with the

```
php artisan storage:link
```

else you can use this

A simple fix for the issue (linked broken error)
in `.env` file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

this replace with the

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

then the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Sometimes when you run more than one project and http://localhost:8000 is already in use, remember that if you use http://localhost:8001 your images might not be visible. You will have to change APP_URL=http://localhost:8000 to APP_URL=http://localhost:8001

Answer (score 2):

delete already generated symlink and then run this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel, consider excluding public folder or any folder where your public files are store in .htacccess from folders that laravel control.

Do it like this in .htaccess

`# Exclude directory from rewriting RewriteRule ^(public/) - [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Storage location before (Not Working) :

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/app/public/media/productImages/'.$list->image)}}" alt="" srcset="">
```

Working storage location :

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/media/productImages/'.$list->image)}}" alt="" srcset="">
```

Else try :

1. Deleting all the linked/shortcut folders created in public folder
2. Then recreating the link by running :

> php artisan storage:link

Answer (score -1):

[Goto **public** Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKed0.png)

Delete the storage shortcut
Then create Another shortcut for **storage** Folder
[Create Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pg4I.png)
[Storage Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ybKd.png)
Then run **php artisan storage:link**