# Laravel 5.3 - Issue displaying Images from public folder using @extends & @sections

Tags: css, image, laravel, laravel-5.3

2nd Update:

For some reason the `display: table;` in my `.header_table` within home.blade.php was preventing the image from rendering.

**UPDATE:**

I should have mentioned that I am trying to display an image within a `@section ( i like to call them partials)`. When I went to my main.blade.php and did the `{{ Html::image('images/max.jpg') }}` link it displayed my image with no issue.

**My questions now:**

How do I display an image within a @section (partial)?

project_name/public/images/max.jpg - path confirmed

views/pages/home.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')



    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/fade.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>


        .header {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: ;
        }

        .header img {
            width: 500px;
        }

        .header_table {
            display: table;
        }



        .table {
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-top: 40px;

        }

        .table h1 {
            text-align: left;
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
            font-size: 90px;
            margin-top: 2px;


        }

        .table p {
            text-align: left;
            color: black;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

        }

        .button {

            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-left: 90px;

        }

        .animate {
            padding-top: 4em;
            padding-bottom: 4em;
        }

        .animate img {
            position: relative;

        }

        .tablet {
            height: 280px;
        }



    </style>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="header header_table">
           {{ Html::image('images/max.jpg') }}
            <div class="table">
                <div id="title"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
                <img src="{{asset('public/images/max.jpg')}}"></img>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <button class="button">Learn More</button>
                <button class="button">Sign-Up</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="animate">
            <img class="tablet" src="https://designcode.io/cloud/ios9-ipad/ipad.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

views/vendor/main.blade.php

```
    <body>

        <ul>
          <li class="logo"><img src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></li>  
          <li><a href="{{ url('gallery') }}">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="container">

    @yield('content')

    </div>


</body>
```

**Previous:**

I'm just trying to display an image that is saved within my project.

I followed this (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) to update my composer.json file and app.php. Ran composer update there after.

I've used :

```
<img src="public/images/image.jpg">
{{ Html::image('public/images/max.jpg') }}
{{ HTML::image('public/images/max.jpg') }}
{{!! Html(or HTML)::image('public/images/max.jpg') !!}}
```

Now:

```
{{URL::asset("public/images/max.jpg")}}
{{ Html::image('images/max.jpg') }}
```

and I keep getting that image icon, but no image. Similar to what this person experienced ([Image not displaying in view. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007448/image-not-displaying-in-view-laravel)). When I try that answer's advice by doing the `asset()` method, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Edit: changed image.jpg to max.jpg 
Edit: added new attempts

Comment: Did you check permission file?

Comment: try to use asset() and remove "public/" from source

Comment: try this `<img src="{{asset('images/image.jpg')}}">`

Comment: Akkapong - it displays this in text on my webpage - http://localhost:8000/images/max.jpg

Comment: Raunak - <img src="{{asset('images/max.jpg')}}"> doesnt even show the image icon. <img src="{{asset('public/images/max.jpg')}}"> shows the image icon

Comment: what do you mean by **image icon** ? is this your image path `your_project/public/images/max.jpg`?

Comment: Raunak - Image icon is the mini pic of the mountain and the clouds, you typically see it when an image isnt displaying. Look at the second link in my post for an example. Yes that is my path

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried `{{URL::asset("public/images/max.jpg")}}`?

Comment: @Obsidian Age- My bad, I did try that one, will edit post. I did it again and it displays in text on my webpage - {http://localhost:8000/public/images/max.jpg}

Comment: @staredecisis: Oh you mean to say broken image; and if `<img src="{{asset('public/images/max.jpg')}}">` image is getting rendered and it is not showing broken image then it might be you have an white or transparent image or the image is of similar to site background color so you cannot able to see that.

Comment: @RaunakGupta - Thank you for the correction; broken link. I removed the background color of the div that holds the img tag and I'm still seeing the same broken link. Do I need to do anything to my routes perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `LaravelCollective's` `Html` Facade, you have used an extra directory in your `image path`.

```
{{ Html::image('public/images/max.jpg') }}
```

Which should be:

```
{{ Html::image('images/max.jpg') }}
```

As `Html` Facade suppose you are inside the `public` directory and searches the image from the specified location.

**Edit:**

You are using:
@extends('main')

It supposes you have a `main.blade.php`  in your `resources/views/main`.

But you have your `main.blade.php` inside `views/vendor/main.blade.php`

You could try:

```
@extends(vendor.main)
```

Also you are doing something wrong. You are adding all the `scripts and css` from the child view to parent view.

When you are using in this format it renders to this form of your `html`.

**Updated Example:**

My views path:

```
|-resources
    |- views
         |- pages
             |- home.blade.php
         |- welcome.blade.php
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Image from Parent</p>
            {{ Html::image('images/capture.png') }}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.blade.php:**

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>This is a child view.</p>
    {{ Html::image('images/capture.png') }}
    </div>
@stop
```

**routes/web.php:**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});
```

I prefer using `@stop` instead of `@endsection`. You could try both to test it.

Hope it helps you. Not confirmed why the image is not rendered.

If it doesn't render could you add the content of `<image src>` from your browser?

**Final Output:**

[image: Final Output]

Comment: No image and now no broken link after removing  public/

Comment: @staredecisis I have just tried and is working for me. Could you post me your public directory snapshot?

Comment: @staredecisis could you post what is inside your `<image src>` url?

Comment: My issue changed. See above. I should have mentioned this was being done through a partial view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the `@section` content too?

Comment: I posted it. Let me know if you need to see more. Thanks

Comment: @extends('vendor.main')  gives me an error and says its not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134545/discussion-between-paladin-and-staredecisis).

Answer (score 1):

Most convenient way to way to store and access images is by using [Laravel filesystems](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem).

First you got to set up your file driver driver `config/filesystems.php`

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

This will enable you to store your images in `storage/app/public`

Lets say you are storing images in `storage/app/public/your_storage_directory` directory. So do as follows.

```
$image = request()->file('banner');
$path = $image->store('your_storage_directory', 'public');
// persist $path in your table
```

`$path` will contain someting simillar to `your_storage_directory/3ca37bc0cdf2f71eeadf60057c71154b.jpeg`

Then do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

To create a symbolic link at `public` directory pointing to `storage/app/public`

Then you only got to do is access the image from your blade file by using following syntax

```
<img src="{{asset($path)}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

> To generate path till `public` directory you have to use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) helper methord,
>   and to display image you have to echo that path inside `img` *`src`*
>   attribute.

This should work for you.

```
<img src="{{asset('images/max.jpg')}}">
```

*Assuming you have max.jpg in `your_project/public/images/max.jpg`.*
Hope this helps!