# Dropzone no valid MIME type in backend Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, dropzone.js

I have really no idea where the problem resides to be honest.

Might be Dropzone, Laravel (5.4), ... So I truly hope even a thought might help me get past this problem.

When I upload files, I don't get any js issues but Laravel throws me following error (for each file):

Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::store()

This is my backend code (Error is set in the portfolioStore method):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UploadPortfolioPhotoRequest; use App\PortfolioPhoto; use DebugBar\DebugBar; use Illuminate\Http\Request; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class AdminController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }

    public function portfolioIndex()
    {
        $photos = PortfolioPhoto::all();

        return view ('admin.portfolio.index')->with('photos', $photos);
    }

    public function portfolioStore(UploadPortfolioPhotoRequest $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->files as $photo) {
            $filename = $photo->store('photos');

            $test = PortfolioPhoto::create([
                'filename' => $filename,
                'title' => 'title',
                'alt' => 'alt'
            ]);
        }

        return 'Upload successful!';
    }

    public function portfolioDelete()
    {
        return view ('admin.portfolio.index');
    } }
```

In any case, here is my Dropzone config:

```
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    url: "/admin/portfolio", // Set the url
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoDiscover: false,
    autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    headers: {
        'x-csrf-token': document.querySelectorAll('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttributeNode('content').value,
    }
});

myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    // Hookup the start button
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
});

myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
    // And disable the start button
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});

// Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
    var alertMsg = document.createElement('div'),
        actions = document.getElementById('actions');
    alertMsg.setAttribute('class', 'alert bg-success');
    alertMsg.innerHTML = 'Files successfully uploaded<a href="#" class="pull-right"><em class="fa fa-lg fa-close"></em></a>';
  actions.parentNode.insertBefore(alertMsg, actions.nextSibling);
});

// Setup the buttons for all transfers
// The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
// `clickable` has already been specified.
document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function() {
    myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
};
document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
};
```

Here is the view:

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Upload images</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="alert bg-danger" role="alert"><em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;</em>
                                    <ul style="display: inline-block;">
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                    <a href="#" class="pull-right"><em class="fa fa-lg fa-close"></em></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div id="actions" class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><span>Add files...</span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> <span>Start upload</span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> <span>Cancel upload</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="files" id="previews">
                                <div id="template" class="file-row">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="media-left">
                                            <img data-dz-thumbnail/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h4 class="media-heading name" data-dz-name></h4>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong></div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
                                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9 text-right">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                                        <span>Start</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                                                        <span>Cancel</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                                        <span>Delete</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Portfolio</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        @foreach($photos as $photo)
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>@endsection

@push('styles')
<link href="{{asset('css/vendor/dropzone.css')}}"/>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
<script src="{{asset('js/vendor/dropzone.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/vendor/initialize/dropzone.cfg.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

So now I'm wondering whether the issue is related to a MIME type being undefined which cause the store method to not work. Or should I be looking elsewhere?

Any advice, ideas welcome :)

Comment: can you show the html form where drop zone is initialized

Comment: @AatishSai Hey thanks for your reply, I added the view to my post.

Comment: if you were to `dd($photo);`in the foreach, does it return an object?

Comment: @mbozwood unfortunately not. As if the dd() isn't used.

Comment: Found any solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `$request->files` does not exist in the Laravel codebase. Since the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class extends the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` class, the `files` [refers to](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1dfdc628b085543e8a4c5cb829202df99ab4b994/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L102) the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag` class which does happens to contain numerous `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`s that do not have the store method.

Simple fix:
Replace `$request->files` with `$request->allFiles()` which should give you an array of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` classes which have the store method

Feel free to shoot any questions in the comment section if you need further help

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be no issue of dropzone.js to me. 
The error says "undefined method..." in the backend (laravel), so the method is not available to your object `photo`.

Have a look at the docs in laravel. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads)

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
foreach ($request->files as $photo) {
    $path = Storage::putFile('photos', $photo);
...
```

Comment: I thought of using this as well: but then I get: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::hashName()....

Comment: Can you please provide the full code of your backend class?

Comment: I've replaced the backend function with the whole class.

I haven't included the request as it passes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but in my case it was simply not having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property included in the `<form>` tag. Once I did that it worked. And I see you also don't have `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="/route" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- your code for dropzone goes here -->
</form>
```

And on a side note, in your `portfolioStore()` method in your `AdminController` controller you have,

```
foreach ($request->allFiles() as $photo) {
    $filename = $photo->store('photos');

    $test = PortfolioPhoto::create([
        'filename' => $filename,
        'title' => 'title',
        'alt' => 'alt'
    ]);
}
```

**Please Don't do it!**

You're creating too many insert queries here.

Refactor it as follows. You can get away with one db query :)

```
$photos = [];
foreach ($request->files as $photo) {
    $filename = $photo->store('photos');

    $photos[] = [
        'filename' => $filename,
        'title' => 'title',
        'alt' => 'alt'
    ];
}
PortfolioPhoto::createMany($photos);
```

And also in a previous post I answered how to convieninetly store files in Laravel. you can [check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972141/3918473). it could improve your `$filename = $photo->store('photos');` part.

Hope this would help you :)

Comment: This wont work. $request->files returns `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag` which does not have the `store` method. Replace `$request->files` with `$request->allFiles()`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

In Laravel you access uploaded files [using the `file` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files), which takes the name of the file input as a parameter.  And from [the Dropzonejs docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage):

> The uploaded files can be handled just as if there would have been a html input like this:
>   `<input type="file" name="file" />`

So try this:

```
foreach ($request->file('file') as $photo) {
```

Comment: This shows up as an invalid argument (supplied for foreach()).

Comment: What do your file inputs look like?

Comment: It doesn't have a direct file input. All is done through the Dropzone configuration.

Comment: Ah sorry - answer updated.  Dropzone uses 'file' as the input name, AFAIK.  You can double check by just doing `return $request->all()` in `portfolioStore()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just dump your $request object, dropzone may send base64_encoded images, that are not in $request->files array.

Anotherway, you can use 
https://github.com/bnbwebexpertise/laravel-attachments

This is very helpful package to work with files.