# Image not showing in view Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-8

It was working when i first did it and then suddenly stopped working.

This is my `URL`

```
{{url('storage/profilepictures/'.Auth::user()->profilepicture )}}
```

and I have already used this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007448/image-not-displaying-in-view-laravel

Comment: @ZiaYamin unfortunately, no.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: maybe the user does not have any photos.

Answer (score 0):

use from `asset` instead of `URL`:

```
<img src="{{asset('/storage/profilepictures' .Auth::user()->profilepicture)}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
```

and if you want to get loggedin user photo, you can get it like below:

```
 Auth::user()->profilepicture
```

or:

```
auth()->user()->profilepicture
```

Comment: broken image link

Comment: does it have any photo?

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that you have recorded the img in storage/app/public/profilepictures/hashed_picture and the recorded data in db is the same like the hashed_picture. If this is all right, that sentence must work

```
<img src="{{url('storage/profilepictures/'.Auth::user()->profilepicture)}}">
```